# Zend DB - Max Time does not return the latest time

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

I have the follow table value with timestamp.

```
[ttimestamp] column
2013-07-11 11:52:19
2013-07-11 11:52:23
2013-07-11 11:52:27
```

However, instead of return the latest time with the following query, it returns the smallest... Why?

```
$select = $this->dbo->select(array("MAX(ttimestamp)"))
    ->from(array('t' => 'table'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784. Not sure what version your running. but it should work if you do `MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ttimestamp))`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working.. Can I replace it with astInsertValue?:(

Comment: It it not returning the last inserted row based on time. Even with UNIX_TIMESTAMP